# Google Optimize and Angular bug

Tags: angular, axios, google-optimize

We have an Angular 9 application running and have some Redirect tests with Google Optimize.

Optimize is loaded through async observable in the app.componenent.ts to make initial payload smaller. But for some weird reason, that we can't tell why yet, as soon that we have any test started, we're having GET requests with this error `IO: Stream cancelled by CLIENT`.

We are using axios lib, that internally uses `window.fetch`, but we still had the issue using `window.fetch`. We found this [issue in Axios Github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2367) but it's not clear why this is happening. We have the team looking into it, but can't replicate this issue on local, dev or QA environment.

Our other strategy is to try different ways of loading Optimize, but the client is concerned about this option since we have lots of errors and still can't replicate the error in other environment.

Any one has experience something close to this that could help us give a light into the project?